# Creating a Email Signature using GMAIL API

Tags: gmail-api

I have configured a python script that changes Email Signature of the user using gmail API. But the problem is by default it has the name as My Signature. Is there any way that I can use custom name instead of My signature?

And also is there anyway to create a new signature rather than updating My Signature. (Using GMAIL API)?

Comment: You can do it manually though the gmail web application other than that what you are doing is the only way i know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Gmail API to update/modify signatures will always apply to 'My Signature' which is the default signature for a gmail account.

If your only concern is changing/creating a new signature, you can always do it via Gmail directly.

Comment: Yes I thought it might be default. But I was just asking to see if there is a way to do that or not. Thanks for the reply